# Thrust CUDA compute index for each segment in an array

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I have an array of int which serves as keys in my application. This is already sorted. I want to assign each unique key a unique index starting from 0. How would I do that in cuda using thrust?

```
    int* sorted_keys = {1, 1, 1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 19, 19, 20}
    // Some thrust operation to get a new array as
    index_for_sorted_keys = {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3}
```

Each segment can be of any arbitrary length.

Answer (score 2):

There are probably many ways to do it. One possible way: [`thrust::adjacent_difference()`](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__transformations_ga0a47f6c0431b0905eaccc7bc427af396.html#ga0a47f6c0431b0905eaccc7bc427af396) with a binary op that produces 0 when the values are the same and 1 in any other case, followed by [a prefix sum](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__prefixsums.html).

Here is a worked example:

```
$ cat t1537.cu
#include <thrust/adjacent_difference.h>
#include <thrust/scan.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/copy.h>

using namespace thrust::placeholders;
int main(){

    int sorted_keys[] = {1, 1, 1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 19, 19, 20};
    int ds = sizeof(sorted_keys)/sizeof(sorted_keys[0]);
    thrust::device_vector<int> d_sk(sorted_keys, sorted_keys+ds);
    thrust::device_vector<int> d_r(d_sk.size());
    thrust::adjacent_difference(d_sk.begin(), d_sk.end(), d_r.begin(), !(_1==_2));
    d_r[0] = 0;
    thrust::inclusive_scan(d_r.begin(), d_r.end(), d_r.begin());
    thrust::copy(d_r.begin(), d_r.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
$ nvcc -o t1537 t1537.cu
$ ./t1537
0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,
$
```